# is it possible to make the TextSpan auto wrap in flutter

Tags: flutter

Now I am using this code to render some text:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
    body: Form(
      key: GlobalKey(),
      child: Center(
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            SelectableText.rich(
              TextSpan(
                children: [
                  TextSpan(text: "sfwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )));
}
```

but the text was overflow, is it possible to make it auto wrap accord the screen size and do not overflow? The rendered text was a dynamic string and I did not know the length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the `SelectableText` with the [Flexible](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html) widget.

As:

```
Flexible(child: 
            SelectableText.rich(
              TextSpan(
                children: [
                  TextSpan(text: "sfwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww"),
                ],
              ),
            )),
```